# Properties of trees

Tags: graph-theory

I need to show that the three following statements are equivalent:

1. $G$ is a tree.
2. Every closed walk in a connected graph $G$ uses all of its edges at least twice
3. Every closed walk in a connected graph $G$ uses at least one of its edges at least twice.

I've been able to show that $1 \implies 3$ and $3 \implies 1$. It's easy to show that $2 \implies 3$, however I can't quite figure out how to show that $3 \implies 2$ or $1 \implies 2$ to complete the equivalences.

I've been mainly trying to prove $1 \implies 2$. It would be easy if all walks were made up of two paths: $u, \ldots, v, \ldots, u$. Since there's only one path between $u$ and $v$ in a tree, each edge would have to be traversed twice. But a walk could be constructed out of a lot more than two paths like my example ($u, \ldots, v, \ldots, w, \ldots x, \ldots, y, \ldots, z, \ldots u$), so I'm a little confused about how to proceed.

I would appreciate a push in the right direction.

Comment: Use the fact that in a tree there is only one path between two edges.

Comment: @CarryonSmiling Right. I was trying to use that fact in my argument, but my argument seemed to be incorrect when I started adding in extra vertices...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Continuing the argument I had in the question:

If a closed walk has the form $uv$-path, $vu$-path, it's obvious to see that every edge is traversed twice.

If a closed walk has the form $uv$-path, $vw$-path, $wu$-path, then there are two cases:
Case 1: The $uv$-path is disjoint from the $vw$-path.
$\implies$ The $wu$-path will have to travel through $v$ $\implies uv$-path, $vw$-path, $wu$-path $\equiv uv$-path, $vw$-path, $wv$-path, $vu$-path.

Case 2: The $uv$-path is not disjoint from the $vw$-path.
Let $x$ be the last vertex that the $uv$-path and the $vw$-path have in common. Now we have $uv$-path, $vw$-path, $wu$-path $\equiv ux$-path, $xv$-path, $vx$-path, $xw$-path, $wx$-path, $xu$-path.

In either case, we have to traverse each edge twice.

It's possible to extend this to any number of vertices to show that it holds in general.

Answer (score 1):

Hint for $1 \implies 2$: if there is a closed walk which does not use all of its edges at least twice, we can find a leaf (and an edge connected to that leaf) that is visited only once. The only possibility is that you started the walk from that leaf, but this leads to a contradiction with the fact that the walk was closed, because you can never reach the start.

Notice that these three aren't equivalent for infinite trees.